# Gitlab ignores ssh key after my own OS was reinstalled

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I've just reinstalled Ubuntu and created new user. The next what I did was generating new ssh key and adding it to my gitlab account. When I try to make git pull or git push git asks for a password for user 'git'.
SSH key was generated using gitlab manual:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my email"
```

All other users of this gitlab server work perfectly with keys.

Comment: Where did you put your newly generated key?

Comment: @Francesco at the default path - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by appending own rsa key to the end of authorized_keys file of host's 'git' user.

Comment: Was the email you used when generating the key the same email you use for GitLab? They need to match for GitLab to accept the SSH key.

Comment: Yes, they was the same.